# Matching first letter of word

Tags: regex, perl, match

I want to match the first letter of a word in one string to another with the similar letter. In this example the letter H:

```
25HB matches to HC
```

I am using the match operator shown below:

```
my ($match) = ( $value =~ m/^d(\w)/ );
```

to not match the digit, but the first matching word character. How could I correct this?

Comment: `\w` includes letters, numbers and underscore.  Letter only alternatives might be `[[:alpha:]]`, `[\p{PosixAlpha}]` or `[\p{XPosixAlpha}]`.

Comment: Your pattern says you want the start of the string, the literal character `d` and one char from the `\w` character group after that. I suggest you take a look at this: https://regex101.com/r/bQ8bM7/1

Comment: Also I don't understand exactly what the goal is. Where is the `HC` in your example. Can you show sample input and sample output or try to give the explanation in different words?

Comment: Downvoted because I have a problem described by the title, but your question body is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That regex doesn't do what you think it does:

```
m/^d(\w)/
```

Matches 'start of line' - letter `d` then a single `word character`.

You may want:

```
m/^\d+(\w)/
```

Which will then match one or more *digits* from the start of line, and grab the first `word character` after that.

E.g.:

```
my $string = '25HC'; 

my ( $match ) =( $string =~ m/^\d+(\w)/ );
print $match,"\n";
```

Prints `H`

Answer (score 1):

You could try `^.*?([A-Za-z])`.

The following code returns:

```
ITEM: 22hb
MATCH: h

ITEM: 33HB
MATCH: H

ITEM: 3333
MATCH:

ITEM: 43 H
MATCH: H

ITEM: HB33
MATCH: H
```

Script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @array = ('22hb','33HB','3333','43 H','HB33');
for my $item (@array) {
    my $match = $1 if $item =~ /^.*?([A-Za-z])/;
    print "ITEM: $item \nMATCH: $match\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not clear about what you want. If you want to match the first letter in a string to the same letter later in the string:

```
m{
  (              # start a capture
    [[:alpha:]]  # match a single letter
  )              # end of capture
  .*?            # skip minimum number of any character
  \1             # match the captured letter
}msx;            # /m means multilines, /s means . matches newlines, /x means ignore whitespace in pattern
```

See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more details.

**Addendum:**

If by word, you mean any alphanumeric sequence, this may be closer to what you want:

```
m{
  \b             # match a word boundary (start or end of a word)
  \d*            # greedy match any digits
  (              # start a capture
    [[:alpha:]]  # match a single letter
  )              # end of capture
  .*?            # skip minimum number of any character
  \b             # match a word boundary (start or end of a word)
  \d*            # greedy match any digits
  \1             # match the captured letter
}msx;            # /m means multilines, /s means . matches newlines, /x means ignore whitespace in pattern
```

Comment: You are right, my example was not clear. I wanted to check if the first letter of the word was a match. It's hard to articulate but in 12HB and 56HA, H would be the first letter in each and also a match. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

(If you can provide more clear example of what you are looking for we may be able to help you better)

The following code takes two strings and finds the first non-digit character common in both the strings:

```
my $string1 = '25HB';
my $string2 = 'HC';

#strip all digits
$string1 =~ s/\d//g;
foreach my $alpha (split //, $string1) {
    # for each non-digit check if we find a match
    if ($string2 =~ /$alpha/) {
        print "First matching non-numeric character: $alpha\n";
        exit;
    }
}
```