# Perl - Print first letter of column

Tags: perl

I'm trying to print the first letter of column2 of an input file as well as other columns of interest. I'm not sure why the following script, adapted from [Matching first letter of word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354435/matching-first-letter-of-word) gives me an 'Use of uninitialized value $columns[2]' warning.

Input File Example:

```
ATOM      1  CAY GLY X   1      -0.124   0.401  -0.153  1.00  2.67      PEP   
ATOM      2  HY1 GLY X   1      -0.648   0.043  -1.064  1.00  0.00      PEP   
ATOM      3  HY2 GLY X   1      -0.208   1.509  -0.145  1.00  0.00      PEP
```

Output File Example:

```
   1  C  -0.124   0.401  -0.153  1.00  2.67       
   2  H  -0.648   0.043  -1.064  1.00  0.00        
   3  H  -0.208   1.509  -0.145  1.00  0.00
```

Script

```
open (my $input_fh, "<", $filename) or die $!;
    while (my $data = <$input_fh>) {
            chomp $data;
            my @columns = split(/\t/, $data);
            my ($firstletter) = ($columns[2] =~ m/^\d+(\w)/);
        if (/CAY/../HT2/) 
        print $output_fh join ("\t", $columns[1], $firstletter, $columns[6], $columns[7], $columns[8]), "\n";
            }
```

**UPDATE** The warning occurred due to the `if (/CAY/../HT2/)` statement for some reason -- but since the input files are identical, I don't really need this condition. Also, since there are no digits in column2 it is more appropriate to use the `/^(\w)/` regex.

Comment: _'Use of uninitialized value $columns[2]'_ is a warning not an error.

Comment: mybe you have a blank line in your file?

Comment: Why curly braces in print statement?

Comment: See another way (updated to fix typos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some particular reason that you must split on tabs?  Getting various kinds of white space in an arbitrary text file correctly can be picky. If not necessary, it seems fully fitting to just split by (any) space, then grab the first letter

```
my @cols = split '\s+', $data;
my ($firstletter) = $cols[1] =~ m/^(\w)/;
```

I am not sure what the rest does but you can easily pluck the columns you need.

Comment: I think because this `1  CAY GLY X   1` is a second column which internally splits data by spaces. So he maybe required just '\t+'

Comment: @EugenKonkov Right, I figured that the whole phrase is considered one column.  However, that is not maintained in the output, `1 C` (none of the rest). Also, he clearly needs to get inside of it, and if it need be put back at some point having it in array slots is easy.  (I'd even say better, since individual words can be manipulated separately.)  But that's why I started by asking -- I don't know whether it has to go by tabs. It just didn't seem so.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug what you get after splitting:

```
my @columns = split(/\t/, $data);
local $" = "\n"; print "$data\nSplitted into:\n@columns";
```

As guess your file have double \t characters. I mean you probably have:
`ATOM\t\t1 CAY GLY X...` so second column is `undef`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the code that gave that warning was not what you show but instead had something like

```
($columns[2]) = ($columns[2] =~ m/^\d+(\w)/);
```

And you are getting the warning because the regex is failing due to not finding a digit. Maybe you meant `\d*`?

Answer (score -3):

For me, maybe i would like to use cut command and pipeline, then split command to get the exact info you want.